# SQL Unit Testing Stored Procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am new to working with SQL database but have been confronted with testing my database.  For security reasons any queries or updates are done through stored procedures.

It was suggested to me by a peer to use stored procedures to test other stored procedures.  Is this a good or bad solution to unit testing my stored procedures to ensure they are doing what they are suppose to be doing?

Comment: An alternative way to test your database stored procedures is using [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found an excellent solution using Visual Studio:
[Visual Studio Unit Testing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851203%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

It allows you to create unit tests for SQL stored procedures, you can also populate the database using regular expressions - very cool stuff.

Answer (score 7):

Apart from [DbUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) and [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) you can use [tSQLt](http://tsqlt.org/) if you like writing tsql. [tSQLt](http://tsqlt.org/) is an open source framework written in tsql for writing unit test cases for tsql.

Answer (score 2):

DbUnit from dbunit.org is a good framework. Another great tools are TSqlUnit and tsqlt from tsqlt.org.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the which tool can do a unit test for the SQL statements or store procedures.
I usually write the SQL script to do a test for that.

1. Create an empty database, of course, the same structure as the original one.
2. Prepare the data (import some data from the original database).
3. Invoke the stored procedure.
4. Then see the data if it's correct or not.

Sometimes write some assert statements like the

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM XX INNER JOIN XXX ON XXXXXXXX WHERE XXX=XXX)
     RAISEERROR XXXXXX
```

If some exceptions or errors are thrown then you can check the stored procedure.

But it's a waste of time.

I usually check all the executing path for the stored procedure most of the time, and just test the main error expecting points.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [TST](http://tst.codeplex.com/) as testing framework for SQL Server with very positive results. 
It works well and I could even integrate it as part of our CI-environment in Team City.

The key is to be very careful on how to set up your test data. Whatever test framework you choose, be sure to apply the Test Data Builder pattern. If you don't, you may very quickly get some test refactoring problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using TestContainer(Mysql) to mock mysql server.
Using Kotlin/Java JUnit5 as the test runner.
so in the test case, it will

1. start TestContainer
2. seed data that is required for the test.
3. execute the Stored Procedure.
4. assert that the data is accurate.