# Maintaining Someones Stored Procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this question - a developer who wrote very complex stored procedures and he/she left the organization. Now you're taking his part and make that same stored procedure to work very fast or like work as earlier to get the same results. What are the steps do we need to follow. In other words, it's like working on someone's impending work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored procedures are notoriously hard to maintain. I would start by writing [unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126296/sql-unit-testing-stored-procedures) - this could involve setting up a dedicated test environment, with "known good" data. Figure out the major logic branches in the procs, and write unit tests to cover those cases. This should make you more familiar with the code.

Once you have unit tests, you can work on optimization (if I've understood your question, you're trying to improve performance). If your performance optimization involves changing the procs, the unit tests will tell you if you've changed the behaviour of the code.

Make sure you keep the unit tests up to date, so that when you leave, the next person doesn't face the same challenge!

Answer (score 1):

First, look at the execution plan of the stored procedure.  Make sure you understand why the SQL Server optimization engine choose these plan over another execution plan, which index it used and why, how statistics works, ...

Then, make it better.

Theses are the steps you need to follow.

1. Understand what's being done
2. Make it better
3. Repeat.